# Error on azure release pipeline:No agent found in pool 'some pool' which satisfies the specified demands: Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.155.1

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am deploying from azure devops using a self hosted deploy agent, using azure release pipelines.

The deployment pool is shared and served by one deploy agent running on a windows 2019. All works well for the old project.

I created a new project that consumes the same deployment pool.
When i submit a new Release to the pool i got the error:

```
No agent found in pool DEV Server Pool which satisfies the specified demands: Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.155.1
```

I try forcing update on the deployment pool, from the "Organization Settings"->"Deployment Pools" page, but the agent is not upgraded.

How i can i fix this? Should the agent self-upgrade?

Comment: According to the error message, you seem to have configured the demands, but the release pipeline cannot find the agent with version 2.155.1. You could open Organization Settings->Deployment Pools->click "..."->click the button Update targets to update it. We could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#demands-that-dont-match-the-capabilities-of-an-agent) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, it seems that you are using self-hosted agent instead of deployment group, please check the pic below. [Demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) and capabilities are designed for use with self-hosted agents so that jobs can be matched with an agent that meets the requirements of the job. If it doesn't match, we will get the error message: `No agent found in pool {pool name} which satisfies the specified demands: {Demand}`

[image]

Also we could download the self-hosted agent(version 2.155.1) via this [page](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases/tag/v2.155.1) and then install the agent under the agent pool `DEV Server Pool`, It will also work.

We could also refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#agent-version-and-upgrades) to update the self-hosted agent.

Comment: it was that, i was using a self hosted agent that unfortunately i gave the same name of the deployment group long ago.